# How to solve the error "object.__new__() takes no parameters"?

Tags: python

I got this type of error in runtime

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "C:\Python37-32\python\program\overiding.py", line 17, in <module>
    e1=Employee("Rajesh",9000) 
TypeError: object.__new__() takes no parameters
```

```
class Employee:
    def _init_(self, nm=None, sal=None):
        self.name=nm
        self.salary=sal
    def getName(self):
        return self.name
    def getSalary(self):
        return self.salary

class SalesOfficer(Employee):
    def _init_(self,nm=None,sal=None,inc=None):
        super()._init_(nm,sal)
        self.incnt=inc
        def getSalary(self):
            return self.salary+self.incnt
```

Comment: `_init_` is incorrect. It should have two underscores: `__init__`.

Comment: @Devesh I think by adding the `class Employee` line you may have masked the error. I suspect something else might be in it's place.

Comment: I have just corrected the indentation, the line `class Employee` was in the same line with triple quotes, which caused the line to not show up, I just placed that line in the next line! and then it showed up! Now you last edit overwrote that @NickT :(

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh derp, the revision viewer didn't render it at all. sorry about that https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55962624/1

Answer (score 0):

The constructor function is named `__init__` (with two underscores around init) and not `_init_` (just one underscore), just change that and your code will work

```
class Employee:

    #Fixed this
    def __init__(self, nm=None, sal=None):
            self.name=nm
            self.salary=sal

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def getSalary(self):
        return self.salary

class SalesOfficer(Employee):

    # Fixed this
    def __init__(self,nm=None,sal=None,inc=None):
        super()._init_(nm,sal)
        self.incnt=inc

    def getSalary(self):
        return self.salary+self.incnt


e1=Employee("Rajesh",9000)
print(e1.getName())
print(e1.getSalary())
```

The output will be

```
Rajesh
9000
```

A point to note here then when I tried to run OP's original code, I got  `TypeError: Employee() takes no arguments` instead of `object.__new__() takes no parameters` which the OP gets, but in my opinion, both errors point in the same direction where it says that since no `__init__` was defined, and you cannot set any attributes in the constructor!

Comment: Then what might cause it? I fixed this issue and the code works!

Comment: Also in my case @wim I get `TypeError: Employee() takes no arguments` instead of `object.__new__() takes no parameters` which the OP gets! I think both errors point in the same direction where it says that since no `__init__` was defined, you cannot set any attributes in the constructor!